# SQL Group BY Date and show Latest Entry and Sum of field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table in MS Access:

`tbl_adj_logs`

| ID | EAN | CrtStock | Adjustment | AdjDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3663602056072 | 20 | -1 | 27/09/2023 |
| 2 | 3663602056072 | 24 | 4 | 27/09/2023 |
| 3 | 3663602056072 | 30 | 6 | 28/09/2023 |
| 4 | 3663602056072 | 28 | -2 | 28/09/2023 |
| 5 | 0000003682418 | 22 | 2 | 28/09/2023 |

Basically, when an adjustment is made, the `EAN`, the new value of `CrtStock`, the `Adjustment` made and the adjustment date are saved to the db. ***This can be modified if it makes the next query easier.*** (The Adjustments above are just random numbers they won't really add up, as they would in real-world scenario)

What I need is a query that will show me, for each date, the final stock for that day, and the sum of all adjustments made that day (creating a chart).

Desired output:

| EAN | FinalStock | SumOfAdjustment | AdjDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3663602056072 | 24 | 3 | 27/09/2023 |
| 3663602056072 | 28 | 4 | 28/09/2023 |
| 0000003682418 | 22 | 2 | 28/09/2023 |

The `WHERE` clause is: `WHERE EAN = [Forms]![frm_Main]![search_ean_input]`, the table above has 2 `EAN` in the result just for extra example, the actual result would only show restuls for the EAN from the `WHERE` clause.

My idea, probably not great since I don't know SQL, was to group the results by date, get the last entry since that will hold the most accurate stock of that day and then add all the other Ajustments to get the SUM. I have no idea if this is doable in SQL. This is one of the many failures to achieve this:

```
SELECT a.CrtStock, DateValue(a.AdjDate), SUM(b.Adjustment) AS SumOfAdj
FROM tbl_adj_logs AS a INNER JOIN tbl_adj_logs AS b ON DateValue(a.AdjDate) = DateValue(b.AdjDate)
WHERE a.ID = (     SELECT MAX(c.ID)     FROM tbl_adj_logs AS c     WHERE c.EAN = [Forms]![frm_Main]![search_ean_input]     AND DateValue(c.AdjDate) = DateValue(a.AdjDate) )
GROUP BY a.CrtStock, DateValue(a.AdjDate)
ORDER BY DateValue(a.AdjDate);
```

Comment: What should determine the 'final' stock for the day - the ID sequence? So from the sample data, return record 5 as well as the sum of all 5 records?

Comment: ID is auto-generated, if grouped by date, my logic was that the highest ID will be the last adjustment. However, if there is an additional field that would help with the query I can add that to the table.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you want last record of each date regardless of EAN or do you want last of each date for each EAN? Sample output as text table can be helpful.

Comment: Searching by EAN, for `each day` an adjustment has been made  I want to know:1 - The final stock of that day, last entry will have that info but if you have another way to get that I'm fine with it. 2 - The sum of all Adjustments made that day, not number of adjustments but the SUM of all adjustments made on that particular day.

Comment: If you are filtering by EAN then you want the SUM by EAN? Edit question to show desired output as a table.

Comment: @June7 I have added an exmaple output.

Comment: `-1 + 6 + 4 + -2 + 2 `  equals something other than you final `SumOfAdjustment`, please explain how you got the `2` on `28/09/2023` in you final results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Trax, Here you go.

```
SELECT
    q1.EAN,
    crtStock AS FinalStock,
    q2.SumOfAdjustment,
    q1.AdjDate1 AS AdjDate
FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT
                EAN,
                MAX(ID) AS MaxID,
                Format(AdjDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS AdjDate1
            FROM
                tbl_adj_logs
            GROUP BY
                EAN,
                Format(AdjDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        ) AS q1
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                EAN,
                Format(AdjDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS AdjDate1,
                SUM(Adjustment) AS SumOfAdjustment
            FROM
                tbl_adj_logs
            GROUP BY
                EAN,
                Format(AdjDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        ) AS q2
        ON (q1.AdjDate1 = q2.AdjDate1) AND (q1.EAN = q2.EAN)
    )
    INNER JOIN
    tbl_adj_logs
ON
    q1.MaxID = tbl_adj_logs.ID
WHERE
    q1.EAN = [Forms]![frm_Main]![search_ean_input]
ORDER BY
    q1.AdjDate1,
    q1.EAN DESC;
```

Results without passing the EAN

[image]

Results when passing the EAN 3663602056072

[image]

Comment: It is unclear why "changing the where clause" will solve anything .

Comment: @Luuk
Earlier I provided the where clause like this `WHERE q1.EAN = sss`

Now I have changed to `WHERE q1.EAN = [Forms]![frm_Main]![search_ean_input]` so the same query can be used.

Comment: Not sure who has down voted this answer when it is correct....

Answer (score 0):

This approach will return entire record, including ID field. Since date value does not have time component, must rely on ID field to determine latest record.

```
SELECT tbl_adj_logs.*, Q1.SAD
FROM tbl_adj_logs 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT EAN, AdjDate, Max(ID) AS MID, Sum(Adjustment) AS SAD
    FROM tbl_adj_logs GROUP BY EAN, AdjDate) AS Q1 
ON tbl_adj_logs.ID = Q1.[MID]
WHERE <apply filter as needed>;
```

Can apply dynamic filter to the outer query or base a report on unfiltered query and apply filter to report. My preference is the latter.

Comment: Does not work as intended, it's returning each adjustment as a result. Does not work at all with a where clause.

Comment: It returns the Sum of adjustments as well. If you don't want the individual adjustment, exclude that field. I used wildcard to select fields just to simplify SQL. And WHERE clause with static parameters does work for me. However, you show dates as non-U.S. structure. That can be an issue. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: Edited to simplify SQL.

Answer (score 0):

See another example.
With 1 query in Access constructor

```
SELECT tbl_adj_logs.EAN
   ,tbl_adj_logs.CtrStock as FinalStock
   ,qrEAN_maxId_sum.[Sum_Adjustment] as SumOfAdjusment
   ,qrEAN_maxId_sum.AdjDate
FROM tbl_adj_logs 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tbl_adj_logs.EAN
      ,cdate(int(tbl_adj_logs.AdjDate)) as AdjDate
      ,Max(tbl_adj_logs.ID) AS [Max_ID]
      ,Sum(tbl_adj_logs.Adjustment) AS [Sum_Adjustment]
    FROM tbl_adj_logs
    GROUP BY tbl_adj_logs.EAN,cdate(int(tbl_adj_logs.AdjDate))
) as qrEAN_maxId_sum 
     ON (tbl_adj_logs.ID = qrEAN_maxId_sum.[Max_ID]) 
    AND (tbl_adj_logs.EAN = qrEAN_maxId_sum.EAN)
WHERE bl_adj_logs.EAN = [Forms]![frm_Main]![search_ean_input] ;
```

To simplify the task, you can create one query and use it in the final query.
Query `qrEAN_maxId_sum`  - get max Id by date and sum of Adjastments

```
SELECT tbl_adj_logs.EAN
  ,cdate(int(tbl_adj_logs.AdjDate)) as AdjDate
  ,Max(tbl_adj_logs.ID) AS [Max_ID]
  ,Sum(tbl_adj_logs.Adjustment) AS [Sum_Adjustment]
FROM tbl_adj_logs
GROUP BY tbl_adj_logs.EAN, cdate(int(tbl_adj_logs.AdjDate));
```

Result query - get CtrStock for row with max Id

```
SELECT tbl_adj_logs.EAN
  ,tbl_adj_logs.CtrStock as FinalStock
  ,qrEAN_maxId_sum.[Sum_Adjustment] as SumOfAdjusment
  ,qrEAN_maxId_sum.AdjDate
FROM tbl_adj_logs 
INNER JOIN qrEAN_maxId_sum 
   ON (tbl_adj_logs.ID = qrEAN_maxId_sum.[Max_ID]) 
  AND (tbl_adj_logs.EAN = qrEAN_maxId_sum.EAN)
WHERE bl_adj_logs.EAN = [Forms]![frm_Main]![search_ean_input] 
;
```

Comment: The all-in-one statement errors with "could refer to more than one table".

Comment: I was testing it right now in Acces 2010. Works. No errors issued. There no fields without aliasses.

Comment: I copy/pasted your SQL into Access builder.

Comment: pls, Show full error message text.

Comment: *The specified field 'tbl_adj_logs.CtrStock' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.*

Comment: Could not reproduce the specified error.

Comment: Well, I discovered a misspelled field name: Adjastment should be Adjustment. Went into design view and removed then re-added CtrStock field. Now it works. Something about the copy/paste messed up CtrStock reference. Also removed extraneous JOIN on EAN.

Comment: Thanks. Change Adjastment to Adjusment). This issue "could refer to more then one table" is described here (https://www.devhut.net/access-the-specified-field-could-refer-to-more-than-one-table/).

Comment: Yes, JOIN on EAN is not needed, if Id is unique in table. First, I think, Id unique by EAN.